# Obj C UIWebView with Variable URL Search Query

Tags: objective-c, url, uiwebview, nsstring

How do you use a URL and be able to change part of the URL? I'm new at Objective C.
 Errors at url in all spots!
restaurants is my UIWebView, zip is my UITextField, restlabel is my UILabel.

```
-(void)load {

url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/search?query=%@", restlabel.text];
}


   -(IBAction)gourl {
restlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [zip text]];
[restaurants loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own answer.

```
-(IBAction)gorest {
    restlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [zip text]];

    NSString *url;
    url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Restaurants+in+%@", restlabel.text];
    [restaurants loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];

    next.hidden = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the text from the text field and build the URL in your `gourl` method, not in the `load` method.

```
-(IBAction)goToURL {
  url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/search?query=%@", restlabel.text];
  [restaurants loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
}
```

You can't define a string with a placeholder that will be dynamically changed (I think that was what you were trying to do). You build a string with a "snapshot" of the variables you are referencing.

Comment: I did as you said and the error still shows as "Use of undeclared identifier 'url'.

Comment: You're missing NSURL in from of your url variable.

Comment: @jhilgert00 The NSURL is in the 2nd line.